# HP ALM REST API send xml data using PUT method using Curl & PHP

Tags: php, xml, rest, curl

I am trying to update the tests data in ALM using `REST API` through `Curl` & `PHP`.

```
Step 1 : Check Lock Status => GET method | response => UNLOCKED

Step 2 : Acquire Lock => POST method | response <entity data XML>

Step 3 : Check Lock Status => GET method | response LOCKED_BY_ME

Step 4 : Checkout Versions | Optional

Step 5 : Update data => PUT method | response = http_code = 200 OK
```

Working fine until step 3, skip step 4.

I succeeded until step 3 , I get the response as `LOCKED_BY_ME`. Step 4 I skipped because Versioning concept we don’t have. Wherein Step 5, when I am tying the send the xml data I get error `415 (Unsupported Media)`, I believe which is because the ALM server is not able to identify the data I am sending. I tried it by sending as “`Associative array/XMl/JSON`” but for all I got status code as 415.

Here is my Code.

**Code**

```
$url="http://{Host:port}/qcbin/rest/domains/{domainname}/projects/{Projectname}/tests/{id}/lock";

function update_tests()
{

    $qc=$this->curl_auth();
    $headers = array("DELETE /HTTP/1.1","Content-Type:text/xml");
curl_setopt($qc, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout);
curl_setopt($qc, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($qc, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($qc, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($qc, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,BASEPATH .'cookie.txt');
$res_unlock=curl_exec($qc);
    $resp=curl_getinfo($qc);

    $xml=simplexml_load_string(curl_exec($qc));

    if($xml->LockStatus == 'LOCKED_BY_OTHER' || $xml->LockStatus == 'LOCKED_BY_ME')
{
    $headers = array(
        'Accept: application/xml',
        'Content-Type: application/xml',
    );

    $data= <<<XML
<Entity Type="test">
<Fields>
<Field Name="Name">
<Value>Name of the test</Value> 
</Field>
<Field Name="Status">
<Value>Updated Value</Value>
</Field>
</Fields>
</Entity>
XML;

        curl_setopt($qc, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($qc, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
    curl_setopt($qc, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($qc, CURLOPT_PUT, 1);
    curl_setopt($qc, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
    curl_setopt($qc, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($qc, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $result = curl_exec($qc);
    $resp=curl_getinfo($qc);
}
else
{
        $data='';
        curl_setopt($qc, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    curl_setopt($qc, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($qc, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($qc, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    $res_Lock=curl_exec($qc);
        $resp=curl_getinfo($qc);

        if($resp['http_code'] == 200)
        {
        $headers = array(
           'Accept: application/xml',
           'Content-Type: application/xml',
        );


        $file = BASEPATH."tests.xml";
        $data= <<<XML
<Entity Type="test">
<Fields>
<Field Name="Name">
<Value>Name of the test</Value> 
</Field>
<Field Name="Status">
<Value>Updated Value</Value> 
</Field>
</Fields>
</Entity>
XML;

           curl_setopt($qc, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
               curl_setopt($qc, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
           curl_setopt($qc, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
           curl_setopt($qc, CURLOPT_PUT, 1);
           curl_setopt($qc, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
           curl_setopt($qc, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
           curl_setopt($qc, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
           $result = curl_exec($qc);
           $resp=curl_getinfo($qc);
        }
    }
}
```

I get `415 Error`, I am not able to send the data using `PUT` method.
Appreciate you kind help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the above, it looks like your HTTP header is in the variable $headers but you're setting the curl options for HTTP header from $header.

I've been struggling today with a similar problem with HP ALM. Everything started working correctly when I was 100% sure that the following headers were being set:

Content-Type: application/xml
Accept: application/xml

There appear to be three things to get right for the HP ALM interface to work:

1. The URL - obviously
2. The http headers - nearly isn't good enough
3. The payload - which looks right from the above

The documentation https://almelsevier.saas.hp.com/qcbin/Help/doc_library/api_refs/REST/webframe.html is just about passable.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using CURLOPT_INFILE with a PUT action.  POSTFIELDS is for a POST action.

Comment: Please, explain/expand a little more your answer.